# How to mount External Hard disk having ntfs on 16.04?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive

I have this 1TB hard drive from segate that I am not able to mount.

This is output of sudo fdisk -l  (showing only part related to external drive i need to mount)

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204884992 bytes, 1953525166 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xabc539bb

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1          63 1953520064 1953520002 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Also this is what I see in dmesg when i connect the usb:

```
[  624.763975] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=3008
[  624.763978] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  624.763979] usb 1-3: Product: FreeAgent       
[  624.763981] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[  624.763981] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 2GET4GZ8
[  624.764381] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  624.764541] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[  625.762974] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  FreeAgent        0138 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  625.763330] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  625.763820] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525166 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  625.767373] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  625.767377] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1c 00 00 00
[  625.768593] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  625.775407]  sdb: sdb1
[  625.776584] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  625.931391] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  625.931394] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error   [current] [descriptor] 
[  625.931396] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  625.931398] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[  626.049500] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  626.049504] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error  [current] [descriptor] 
[  626.049506] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  626.049509] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 06 20 da 00 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
[  703.627956] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  703.627959] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  703.627961] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  703.627963] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[  703.666438] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  703.666441] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[  703.666444] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  703.666446] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 06 20 da 00 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
[ 1301.200045] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR   driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1301.200048] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 1301.200049] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1301.200051] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 1301.255510] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1301.255514] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 1301.255516] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1301.255519] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 06 20 da 00 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
[ 1901.208216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1901.208219] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 1901.208220] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1901.208222] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00
[ 1901.267529] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1901.267532] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 1901.267534] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[ 1901.267536] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(12)/Blank a1 06 20 da 00 00 4f c2 00 b0 00 00
```

When I try to mount it I see:

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/anup/FreeAgent/
Failed to open ntfs attribute: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': No such file or directory
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
sudo mkdir /media/anup/FreeAgent/
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/anup/FreeAgent/
```